# HTML5 elements display in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, html

My site works fine in Chrome and Safari but some image elements do not display correctly in Firefox or Internet Explorer. I don't understand how to solve the problem.

The problem occurs [here](http://www.blackstonecreativegroup.com/portfolio.html) and
[here](http://www.blackstonecreativegroup.com/index.html)

The images are paired with captions and triggered by clicking on the row of buttons at the bottom of the page.

```
<div class="slide-caption copy-1">
<div class="slide" id="showcase-1">
```

The captions are working fine. They change when you click the buttons.
But the images paired with the captions do not appear after the first image in FireFox and Internet Explorer.

Or is it the old version of JQuery that's linked? When I tried to update to the latest version of JQuery everything blew apart in all browsers.

Note that I have added 1px outlines to some elements while working on the problems.

The site seemed to be working fine until recently when someone gave me a heads up. I hired a developer for this site a few years ago and now he's no longer available. So any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what version of JQuery are you using? what events are attached to the <div class="scrollable"><div class="items">? The slide captions are just toggles based on the selected list item the real question is what events are firing when a list item is clicked.

Comment: My developer linked to JQuery 1.4.4 One of the first things I tried was linking to JQuery 1.11.1 but that blew apart many elements on the page. I'm not a developer but I believe the javascript events are: `jQuery("#main-slide-nav ul li a.selected").removeClass("selected");
jQuery(jQuery("#main-slide-nav ul li a")[index]).addClass("selected");`

Comment: Ok so based on that there is likely a function that checks for the selected class. so you are looking for a piece of code that reads $(".selected").html this will be the check in a function that will be reading and subsequently performing operations on the slide class. try and find that and post whatever code it is a part of in your question.

Comment: Ok thanks...at the bottom of the html markup is the script:

Comment: `<script> 
$(function() {
$(".scrollable").scrollable();
}); </script>`

Comment: scrollable is the element that includes all the buttons at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Chrome (a webkit-based browser) it works because the `.slider-inner` div is being moved left-and-right using the `-webkit-transform` property. As you may note from the name, that is a webkit browser prefixed command, so it will not work in Firefox.

In Firefox, the `.slide-inner` div is being moved using the CSS property `left`. This would work, except the `.slider-inner` div is not position absolutely. Add the following to your css and it should work:

```
.slider-inner {
    position: absolute;
}
```

As a side note, you could also change the Javascript to use `transform` property which is supported by Firefox.

Comment: OK changing the CSS worked! Thanks so much! I will also update the javascript. Cheers...